# predicative complement vs predicative adjunct

Tags: complements, predicative-complements, adjuncts

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (Page 250) has this passage:
[image]
Here, Od is Direct Object, and Oi is Indirect Object.

It seems that CGEL is saying that *almost raw* in [i-ii] and *fiendishly hungry* in [iii] are all predicative adjuncts, not predicative complements.

In [i] and [iii], I agree that *almost raw* and *fiendishly hungry* are adjuncts. But is *almost raw* an adjunct in [ii] too?

If it is, how about this?

> *He served her steak almost raw.*

Here, is *almost raw* an adjunct too?

Comment: It's all explained in CGEL.

Comment: @BillJ Where in CGEL?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/601225/2085).

Answer (score 2):

All of these can be paraphrased with a *when* statement containing the adjunct,

> She ate her steak *when it was almost raw*.
>
> He served her her steak *when it was almost raw*.
>
> He served her steak *when it was almost raw*.

With predicative complements, this would not be possible,

> He kept her steak almost raw =/= He kept her steak when it was almost raw.
>
> She called the steak almost raw =/= She called the steak when it was almost raw.
>
> Her steak stayed almost raw =/= Her steak stayed when it was almost raw.

In this second set, *almost raw* is an argument of the verb and hence cannot be paraphrased by a construction clearly falling into the adjunct category.

Comment: I doubt the paraphrases in the first set work either. Do you really think, for example, that _He served her steak almost raw_ means the same thing as _He served her steak when it was almost raw_?

Comment: Yes, the meaning is practically the same even if the _when_ version is a bit clunky. There may be some grey area between predicative adjuncts and complements (e.g. _She prefers her steaks almost raw_ =?= _She prefers her steaks when they are almost raw_), but there is a clear difference between the first and second set above.

Comment: I agree that there's a clear difference between the first and second set. But does it necessarily mean that the first set works as you claim? If _almost raw_ were to mean _when it was almost raw_, why is it that _when it was almost raw_ can be fronted but that _almost raw_ cannot? _When it was almost raw, he served her steak_ works, but _Almost raw, he served her steak_ doesn't. Note that _Fiendishly hungry, he offered her the steak_ works too (when _he_ is predicand).

Comment: Adjuncts are optional—the verb does not require them or assign a special interpretation to them. Semantically "almost raw" is called a depictive adjunct. There is a secondary predication construction where such a depictive adjunct can go in a clause after a predicate and its complements. "When" adjuncts are a different kind that can be fronted, but the meaning is similar.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question about:

> He served her steak almost raw.

This sentence is ambiguous. *Her* can be either a possessive/genitive pronoun functioning as determiner, or an accusative pronoun functioning as indirect object.

- Interpretation 1: He served [her steak] [almost raw]
- Interpretation 2: He served [her] [steak] [almost raw]

  - paraphrases: He served [to her] [steak] [almost raw] / He served [her] [some steak] [almost raw]

Either way, *almost raw* is an adjunct: it can be freely omitted without affecting the interpretation of *He served her steak*.

Comment: If sleeping raw is doing so without pajamas, I wonder whether serving raw wouldn't be the same thing. :)